# What is a query offset?

Tags: mysql, kohana

I saw this at the Kohana documentation:

```
$content = new View('pages/items');
$items = new Items_Model;

$content->items = $items->get_items($page_no, 10); // page to get starting at offset, number of items to get
```

As you can see, we can assume that we have get_items method for Items model that receives 2 parameters, $page_no and 10 (as shown here). I know that 10 is the number of items to get and $page_no is the page to get starting at offset

I can probably implement a limit sql statement for the 10 parameter, but what sql statement will correspond to $page_no? What does Kohana mean regarding "page to get starting at offset"

Answer (score 19):

It corresponds to a `LIMIT` statement:

```
SELECT something FROM table LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset;

//or alternatively
SELECT something FROM table LIMIT $offset,$limit;
```

In other words, select something from table, but only give me **`$limit`** records starting from record **`$offset`**.

`$offset = ($page_no - 1) * $limit`
<sub>*`$page_no` is 1 based.*</sub>

More information in the MySQL documentation:

> [12.2.8 SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

**DISCLAMER:** `$limit` and `$offset` is used in this question only to aid understanding. Of course, you do not want to build a query without proper value escaping.

Comment: you might also want to actually multiply the page number by the limit amount, to get the obvious pagination behavior, otherwise, you are only skipping single rows, rather than page-size chunks of rows.

Answer (score 6):

That particular comment unfortunately confuses two common ways to consider pagination or grouping in queries.  The SELECT syntax, as Andrew describes, allows an [OFFSET parameter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#id1121840), the number of items to skip before returning anything.  However, it is most often used with pagination, as in the [pagination library](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/pagination) from which your quotation was taken.  In this case, it is more useful to ask for a specific page number.

To compare the two, consider a case where you've made a search and have gone to page 3, with 10 items per page.  Items 1-20 were on the first two pages; therefore, the OFFSET parameter will be 20:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE searched LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE searched LIMIT 20,10
```

Unfortunately, the `$page_no` parameter in the cited example probably wants to be 3, the page number.  In that case, the SQL offset will have to be calculated.  Given that `get_items` does not seem to be a standard model method, it's probably calculated in there; alternatively, the pagination library seems to have a property called `sql_offset` which probably calculates it for you.  Either way, the calculation is easy enough:

```
$offset = max($page_no - 1, 0) * $limit;
```